# Configuring Sonar plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am having some confusion over configuring `Sonar` *plugin* on `Jenkins`. I went to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** and added `Sonar`.I am confused about what to put in the `Database` URL in the `Sonar` section.

I put

```
jdbc:mysql://10.4.1.206/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

10.4.1.206 is the node I am connecting to.

However, the port is 3306.

Should I put

```
jdbc:mysql://10.4.1.206:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true or just leave it like before?
```

Also, since I am using `MySQL`, do I need to put *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver* in the `Driver` section? It says to leave it blank if I am using embedded default driver.

Please forgive me; this is my first time tampering with both `Jenkins` and `Sonar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have configured your Sonar to use MySQL, you need to provide both the URL and the driver. The default, embedded database for Sonar is Derby - below you will find a sample of a default sonar configuration:

```
# Comment the 3 following lines to deactivate the default embedded database
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sonar;create=true
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                values(1)
```

So, if you have configured your Sonar to use MySQL, and I can only assume that you had, let's analyze the configuration itself:

The driver that you need to explicitly declare is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Yours URL string looks good to me. According to the MySQL Connect specification:

> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database]  » 
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```

In my current setup the connection is as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/radical_sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

I tend to use the port number explicitly in order to avoid confusion rather than anything else - we do have a test MariaDB install running on a different port...

Answer (score 1):

In **Manage Jenkins > Configure System**, your Sonar-Settings should be as follows:

Database URL should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.4.1.206:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

Driver should be:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

If you need more information, you might also want to have a look at your **"sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties"** File and the following documentation link

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin

Good Luck with your configuration!